# How to find offsetTop relative to parent, not window top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is fairly straightforward: How can you find the `offsetTop` of a child element compared to it's parent element (rather than the window top)?

The definition of `offsetTop` states that the property will return the value by which a child element is offset from the top of an `offsetParent`, but this doesn't seem to be the case in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5KBK/.

My goal is to find the offset of the bolded orange text from the top of the scrollable div, not the window top. Is there any way to do this without calculating the heights of the above elements, paddings, margins, etc. and subtracting it from the `offsetTop`?

I'm looking for a JavaScript only solution. No jQuery please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By definition `offsetTop` returns the top position of the object relative to the top side of its `offsetParent` element, in pixels.

Now `offsetParent` needs to be **an element with a position other than static**. If you change the position attribute of `scroll` element in your fiddle I get a value of 1012 as opposed to 1110 without the position attribute.

Comment: Ah, I just found this answer 2 minutes ago. Nevertheless, this answer is still helpful, as it includes a definition. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I did some more research and figured out the answer. The `offsetParent` must have a specified `position:absolute` or `position:relative` declaration, as shown in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5KBK/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed on my end